# How to get route parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a ASP.NET website that is URL-Rewriting enabled. I know how to get route parameters using C#:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
```

But I don't know how to get it from javascript? Following is my rewritten link format:

> http://www.domain.com/topic/{id}/{title}

I want to get this {id} field using JavaScript. Please help!

**UPDATE**

I have this code that gets request parameter.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

How can this be modified to get route parameter?

Comment: Check this post, I think you'll find the solution there: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: URL-parameter is different thing. I don't think it will work.

Comment: if your format is `http://www.domain.com/topic/{id}/{title}` then why don't you `window.location.href` in a string; split it on '/'; and then access the particular index.

Comment: @srvikram13 please provide an example what you exactly want to say.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva check the solution I've posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function getValueAtIndex(index){
    var str = "http://www.sample.com/234/Fiddle/test"; //window.location.href; 
    return str.split("/")[index];
}
console.log(getValueAtIndex(3));
```

### Update

Here's a much cleaner way of getting value at an index in the route using plain JS:

```
    location.pathname.split('/')[index]
```

For example, for the current page,

```
location.pathname = '/questions/20302776/how-to-get-route-parameter'
```

You can get the question id by doing:

```
location.pathname.split('/')[2]

// Notice that the index does not start from zero.
```

Comment: this kinda sucks if working with a virtual directory.

Comment: I like this but split the string into a separate array variable and then use the arrays length - the supplied index - 1 as the array index.  That way it works backwards so 'test' is returned for index 0, 'Fiddle' for index 1 etc.  This would solve the problem of virtual directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
const getRouteValueAt = (idx) => {

   const routeTokens = location.pathname.replace(/^\/+/g,'').split('/')
   //[questions,20302776,how-to-get-route-parameter-in-javascript]

   return routeTokens.length > idx ? routeTokens[idx] : undefined
}
```

Usage

```js
const routeName = getRouteValueAt(0); // questions
const routeId = getRouteValueAt(1); // 20302776
```